# VMWare Tools on Kali Rolling (2016.1) - Shared Folders Problem

Tags: kali-linux, vmware

Here is my system :

```
Kali Linux Rolling - 2016.1 - GNU/LINUX
4.4.0-kali1-amd64

VMWare Workstation 10.0.3
```

---

I upgraded my headers to **4.4.0** by these commands :

```
apt-get update -y  
apt-get upgrade -y  
apt-get dist-upgrade -y  

apt-get install module-assistant  
m-a update  
m-a prepare
```

---

Now i want to install vmware tools on this machine.
So i followed this :
http://docs.kali.org/general-use/install-vmware-tools-kali-guest

---

It seems every thing is ok : **drag, drop, copy, paste** against local machine.
But the problem is about : Shared Folders...
How can i mount shared folder?
This command shows me the shared folder's name : **vmware-hgfsclient** -> My_sh_Folder
But how can i access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently starting after the update from about 5 or 6 weeks ago.

In Linux, open terminal and type:

```
ls /mnt/hgfs
```

You will see a list of shared folders from VMware.  If you don’t see any then try:

```
sudo mount -t fuse.vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs -o allow_other
```

Then when you see the list of shared folders, you can map the path:

```
ln -s /mnt/hgfs/<FOLDERNAME>/ /root/Desktop/<FOLDERNAME>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following worked (Kali 2020.1); where `sharename` is the share created in VMWare, and `mountpoint` is a directory in /mnt/hgfs:

```
vmhgfs-fuse .host:/{sharename} /mnt/hgfs/{mountpoint} -o subtype=vmhgfs-fuse,allow_other
```

In order to make the mount permanent put the followint in `/etc/fstab`:

```
vmhgfs-fuse /mnt/hgfs fuse defaults,allow_other 0 0
.host:/{sharename} /mnt/hgfs/{mountpoint} fuse.vmhgfs-fuse defaults,allow_other 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In kali VMware after looking for several solutions: the solution I have found to why my shared folder is not working even though I have initiated my shared folder in the setting of VMWare is to set the radio button of the shared folder section to "always enabled".

You need to enter another command in terminal to mount your shared folder:

```
sudo mount -t fuse.vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs -o allow_other
```

After typing

```
cd /mnt/hgfs/
```

and then

```
ls
```

you can see the folders in you shared folders.